# Half bridge IC PWM not working properly

Tags: pwm, h-bridge, brushed-dc-motor

I am trying to use an A3916GESTR-T half-bridge to drive a brushed DC motor however I am running into several issues. The largest of these is the fact the output of the half-bridge does not match what I am expecting. The image included shows the output of the motor driver's terminals (OUT1A and OUT1B). The motor driver input 1B is being held low, whilst the other input 1A has a 50% duty cycle at a frequency of
~ 2 kHz (3.3 V). The motor driver is being supplied with 9V, so I am expecting an average of 4.5 V on the output.

[image: H-Bridge Output Waveform]

At lower frequencies (~100 Hz) it works fine.

I have tried attaching a 47 uF capacitor to the power pins of the motor driver which has yielded no change in output.

Is there any reason this is only happening at higher frequencies? and what can I do to try and mitigate this issue.

Thanks.

**2020-06-23 Update**

I think a large part of my problem may have been hardware, and the waveform has improved after replacing the IC, however I am still not achieving a 50% duty cycle. The following images were sampled at 1 MHz.

[image: New hardware]

Here is another image but the PWM frequency is at 20 kHz instead of 2 kHz

[image: High frequency PWM]

Is this due to capacitance on my PCB?

Thanks

Comment: Motor inductance may be enough to repel KHZ frequencies. If 100HZ works why not use it? Do NOT add parallel capacitors or the motor driver may overheat.

Comment: What is your measurement setup? The signal shown looks undersampled. For 2khz I would choose a sampling rate much higher to see the square wave.

Comment: Once you edit your question to include more plots from the commenters above, you can reply back to their comment so it's easy for them to follow up.

Comment: @Sparky256 It seems that frequencies that low cause too much inductor ripple when a brushed DC motor is plugged in, and I can only improve PWM performance on the motor by increasing the frequency. It is usually recommended to use above 2 kHz from what I understand.

Comment: @JG97 I'm sampling at 8 kHz which I thought would have been enough. Currently I don't have access to my set up so I will have to come back to this.

My set up is an oscilloscope with the negative input attached to OUT1B and the positive end attached to OUT1A